# Intuitive explanation of using ACF to determine the order of MA in time series

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

It is intuitive to know why we can only use PACF to determine the order of AR - since ACF will show good correlations even for the lags which are far in the past, as it also cater for indirect effects for lags that already been cater for.

But it is not intuitive why we can only use ACF rather than PACF to determine to order of MA. Could someone offer some intuitive explanation?